# Adding a template/form to a page with Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-transclude

I'm new to Angular and trying to find the best way to add/append a template dynamically to a page. I will have a couple different forms in templates, and when a button is clicked I'd like for one of the templates to be displayed, depending on options that are selected. I'm not entirely sure what suits my needs. I read about transcluding and nginclude, but I don't know which (if either) will fit my situation.

I tried to use transclude, but I couldn't get any content to be added/displayed. I used [this](https://www.accelebrate.com/blog/angularjs-transclusion-part-1/) for reference, but I didn't have any luck. This is what I tried.

```
<!-- index.html -->
<html ng-app = "testApp">
    <some-component></some-component> <!-- this component has the button which the user clicks to display a form -->
    <div added-form>Content here</div> <!-- transclusion here -->
</html>


//javascript controllers/components
app.component("testApp", {
    templateUrl: '/static/angular-testapp/app/components/test-app/test-app.template.html',
    controller: function ($scope, $rootScope, $transclude) {
        ...
    }
});

app.component("someComponent", {
    templateUrl: '/static/angular-testapp/app/components/some-component/some-component.template.html',
    controller: function ($scope, $rootScope, $transclude) {

        //button that when clicked will add the template 
        $scope.addForm = function(event){
            console.log(event); //this shows, so I know the function is being reached
            app.directive('addedForm', function() { //I also tried added-form as the name
              return {
                transclude: true,
                template: "<div>the template</div><ng-transclude></ng-transclude>"
              };
            });
        }
    }
});
```

When I click the button nothing happens. I put a `console.log()` statement in the function and it displays, so I know the button is working at least. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks

**Update**

I'm not 100% sure, but I think my issue is scope related. I moved the code for transcluding that's in the addForm function to be outside of any controllers/components (just at the bottom of the page), and it worked. While that's good to know, I still cannot get transclusion to work from within the function for the button click.

**Update 2**

I got it to work, but not using transclude. I discovered the $templateRequest service. Here's what I used

```
//button that when clicked will add the template 
$scope.addForm = function(event){
    $templateRequest("/path/to/template.html").then(function(html){
        //I added a div to the page with class content
        var element = angular.element( document.querySelector( '.content' ) );
        var template = angular.element(html);
        element.append(template);
        $compile(template)($scope);
   });    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try it this way: https://jsfiddle.net/vts1w7kt/

Just use ng-hide or ng-show based on a model inorder to show the appropiate div, form, etc...

The select is bound to `myDropDown` this way:

```
<select ng-model="myDropDown">
  <option value="one">One</option>
  <option value="two">Two</option>
  <option value="three">Three</option>
</select>
```

Then use the ng-view or ng-hide bound to that model like this:

```
ng-show="myDropDown=='one'"
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not quite what I'm looking for. While that does work and I could use it for future projects, I'd like to figure out why transclude isn't working for me. The main reason is that in case I have large templates to add I don't want them on the main html file cluttering things up.